# How to get the MethodInfo of a function of a class, without string comparison

Tags: c#, reflection, fieldinfo, memberinfo

Similar to a previous question of mine, when I was asking about getting the FieldInfo of a field, [How to get the FieldInfo of a field from the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751420/how-to-get-the-fieldinfo-of-a-field-from-the-value), from the answers there, I compiled this helper class,

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

internal class Program
{
    class MyClass
    {
#pragma warning disable 0414, 0612, 0618, 0649
        private int myInt = 24;
#pragma warning restore 0414, 0612, 0618, 0649

        public const BindingFlags _flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

        public MyClass()
        {
            MemberInfo myIntMI = GetMemberInfo(this, c => c.myInt);
            Console.WriteLine(myIntMI.Name + ": " + GetFieldValue(myIntMI) + ", " + GetFieldInfo(myIntMI).FieldType);

//          MemberInfo tfMI = GetMemberInfo(this, cw => cw.testFunction());
//          MemberInfo tfMI = GetMemberInfo(this, cw => cw.testFunction);
//          Console.WriteLine(tfMI.Name + ": " + GetFieldValue(tfMI) + ", " + GetFieldInfo(tfMI).FieldType);

            foreach( var mi in GetType().GetMethods(_flags) )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("method: " + mi);
            }
        }

        private void testFunction() { }

        private object GetFieldValue(MemberInfo mi)
        {
            return GetFieldInfo(mi).GetValue(this);
        }

        private FieldInfo GetFieldInfo(MemberInfo mi)
        {
            return GetType().GetField(mi.Name, _flags);
        }

        private MemberInfo GetMemberInfo<TModel, TItem>(TModel model, Expression<Func<TModel, TItem>> expr)
        {
            return ( (MemberExpression)expr.Body ).Member;
        }
    }
}
```

Which works perfectly well using the `GetMemberInfo(this, c => c.myInt`, but the commented out line is what I'm confused about now, `GetMemberInfo(this, c => c.testFunction)` or `GetMemberInfo(this, c => c.testFunction())`.

Is there any way, without string comparison, I can get the member info that's available from a `GetMethods()` runthrough, or `GetMethod("testFunction")`?

Comment: I think (but am not in a position to verify) that to be able to pass `c => c.testFunction()` to `GetMemberInfo`, the type of the second parameter would have to be `Expression<Action<TModel>>`.  To be able to pass `c => c.testFunction`, I *think* your parameter would have to be of type `Expression<Func<TModel, Action>>`.  Since `testFunction` doesn't have a return type, `TItem` wouldn't play a role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MemberExpression` is only for properties and fields. You probably look at `MethodCallExpression`.

So something like

```
((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Method
```

assuming that you pass a lambda that looks like `() => this.testFunction()`

So to get the `MemberInfo` you would get a `Method` property of a `MemberCallExpression`.

Also, you should then change the `GetMemberInfo` method signature, because this is a lambda that takes no parameters and returns the same type that your method returns, so it will be a `private MemberInfo GetMemberInfo<T>(Expression<Func<T, void>> expr)` or something close to it.

I'm not 100% sure, but what happens is, `this.testFunction` is actually a syntactic sugar for delegate creation, so it's actually something like `new Action(this.testFunction)` assuming `testFunction` is `void testFunction()`. Or something like this, because `this.testFunction` is not a member access, but rather a delegate creation.

Comment: Shouldn't a method with a return type of `void` be an `Action` rather than `Func<T, void>`?

Comment: But he can try to use this code for methods that can take parameters and return values. Lambda itself will most certainly have no parameters, but it will still have a return type of the method called.

Comment: Perfect.  I re-edited my question when I realised I wanted/needed MethodInfo rather than MemberInfo, but your answer is still correct (nearly).  What I've used is `private MethodInfo GetMethodInfo(Expression<Action> expr) { return ( (MethodCallExpression)expr.Body ).Method; }` which is your answer, along with Ann's suggestion.  Many thanks!

Comment: No problem. For some reason Expressions aren't documented very good and it's pretty easy to get lost with them

Comment: I'd have that opinion about a huge amount of reflection in areas of C#, and if you hop onto IRC, or similar, I've found you get hammered for wanting to do that sort of thing.  With Python, the docs were much better, and the community was a lot more open to that type of coding.